# inApp purchase payment in ios

Tags: in-app-purchase

InApp purchase payment in ios

i need to subscribe a plan using InApp purchase.  for payment but i am showing an alert from sandbox environment like "would you like to buy ...." i need to add my card details and show some sample transaction happening. How to redirect to payment and add card details? how the InApp purchase payment can be done in
real time environment.

```
// MARK: - IAP payment queue
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    hideLoader()

                    if let paymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(paymentTransaction)
                    }

                    if productID == PRODUCT_ID {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isPurchased")
                        lblPurchaseDone.text = "Pro version PURCHASED!"
                        lblPurchaseDone.isHidden = false
                        btnPurchase.isHidden = true
                        btnRestore.isHidden = true
                        self.present(Utilities().showAlertContrller(title: "Purchase Success", message: "You've successfully purchased"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                case .failed:
                    hideLoader()
                    if trans.error != nil {
                        self.present(Utilities().showAlertContrller(title: "Purchase failed!", message: trans.error!.localizedDescription), animated: true, completion: nil)
                        print(trans.error!)
                    }
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                case .restored:
                    print("restored")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                default: break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Credit cards aren't used for in-app purchases. They're done through the user's iTunes account.

Comment: @enc_life after logging in using itunes account how the payment is done?? from where transaction takes process??

Comment: Payment is built in to the user's iTunes account. I would read through Apple's docs or watch some of the videos on in app purchases if it's unclear. https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/